# Why can't I increase session.timeout.ms?

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to increase `session.timeout.ms` to allow longer time for processing the messages received between `poll()` calls. However when I change `session.timeout.ms` to a higher value than 30000, it fails to create Consumer object and throws below error.

Could anyone tell why can't I increase `session.timeout.ms` value or if I am missing something?

```
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig  - ConsumerConfig values: 

request.timeout.ms = 40000
check.crcs = true
retry.backoff.ms = 100
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
receive.buffer.bytes = 262144
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.key.password = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
ssl.provider = null
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
session.timeout.ms = 40000
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
bootstrap.servers = [server-name:9092]
client.id = 
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 50000
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
auto.offset.reset = latest
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 2097152
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
ssl.protocol = TLS
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
group.id = test7
enable.auto.commit = false
metric.reporters = []
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
metrics.num.samples = 2
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException:
>   Failed to construct kafka consumer    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:518)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:500)

Comment: Can you post the entire error stack? there are not enough details to help here.

Comment: Follow this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525311/how-to-set-max-poll-records-in-kafka-connect-api

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The range of consumer session timeout is controlled by broker `group.max.session.timeout.ms`(default 30s) and `group.min.session.timeout.ms`(default 6s).

You should increase group.max.session.timeout.ms first in broker side, otherwise you will get "The session timeout is not within an acceptable range.".

Comment: Thanks but adding/setting group.max.session.timeout.ms=3600000 in config/server.properties still doesn't resolve this. However now I am getting "Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: request.timeout.ms should be greater than session.timeout.ms and fetch.max.wait.ms" error that is helpful.

Comment: This worked after setting request.timeout.ms to a value greater than session.timeout.ms.

Comment: The default value for `group.session.max.timeout.ms` is 30 minutes, not 30 seconds. Source: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_group.max.session.timeout.ms

Answer (score 36):

These conditions needed to be keep in mind to change `session.timeout.ms`:

1. `group.max.session.timeout.ms` in the server.properties > `session.timeout.ms` in the consumer.properties.
2. `group.min.session.timeout.ms` in the server.properties < `session.timeout.ms` in the consumer.properties.
3. `request.timeout.ms` > `session.timeout.ms` + `fetch.wait.max.ms`
4. (`session.timeout.ms`)/3 > `heartbeat.interval.ms`
5. `session.timeout.ms` > Worst case processing time of Consumer Records per consumer poll(ms).

Comment: About the last point, Is worst case processing time `max.poll.interval.ms`? And why does it matter? Isn't a background thread used to keep the session active?

Comment: I have set request.timeout.ms > session.timeout.ms with value of request.timeout.ms=25000, session.timeout.ms=20000 and issue resolved

Comment: Looking back at this, do you still think that was right ? request.timeout.ms has so nothing to do with with the session.timeout.ms ? if so can u explain the correlation here ?

Answer (score 1):

i am using spring-kafka

i had added the following config but the consumer still was not up:

```
buildProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.user-events-min-bytes"));
    buildProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.user-events-wait-time-ms") );
    buildProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.user-events-wait-time-ms") );
    buildProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.user-events-request-timeout-ms"));
    buildProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.user-events-wait-time-ms"));
```

i figured out it was failing because poll.timeout was 1000;
adding the following config helped:

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("kafka.user-events-wait-time-ms")));
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers to this question correctly describe the error and how to increase `session.timeout.ms`, there is a better and more direct way to address the original goal:

> allow longer time for processing the messages received between `poll()` calls

The best way to achieve this in modern Kafka versions is to directly set `max.poll.interval.ms` in the consumer configuration to a higher value.

Most contemporary client libraries today are based on librdkafka, which has a background thread sending heartbeats. The [librdkafka CONFIGURATION](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) documentation describes `session.timeout.ms` as:

> Client group session and failure detection timeout. The consumer sends periodic heartbeats (heartbeat.interval.ms) to indicate its liveness to the broker. If no hearts are received by the broker for a group member within the session timeout, the broker will remove the consumer from the group and trigger a rebalance.

Where as `max.poll.interval.ms` (which defaults to 300000ms, or 5 minutes) is described as:k

> Maximum allowed time between calls to consume messages (e.g., `rd_kafka_consumer_poll()`) for high-level consumers. If this interval is exceeded the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another consumer group member. Warning: Offset commits may be not possible at this point. Note: It is recommended to set `enable.auto.offset.store=false` for long-time processing applications and then explicitly store offsets (using `offsets_store()`) after message processing, to make sure offsets are not auto-committed prior to processing has finished. The interval is checked two times per second. See [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) for more information.

Heartbeat support (KIP-62) was added to Kafka in version 0.10.1. The reason this is better than increasing `session.timeout.ms` is that the broker can distinguish between consumer client entirely disappearing (eg, crashing, network interruptions) and long processing time. In the former case, the broker can rebalance to another consumer faster.

Answer (score 0):

[How to set max.poll.records in Kafka-Connect API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525311/how-to-set-max-poll-records-in-kafka-connect-api)

It was solved. I added below configuration in connect-avro-standalone.properties

group.id=mygroup
 consumer.max.poll.records=1000