# How to set max.poll.records in Kafka-Connect API

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using confluent-3.0.1 platform and building a Kafka-Elasticsearch connector. For this I am extending SinkConnector and SinkTask (Kafka-connect APIs) to get data from Kafka.

As part of this code i am extending taskConfigs method of SinkConnector to return "max.poll.records" to fetch only 100 records at a time. But its not working and I am getting all records at same time and I am failing to commit offsets within the stipulated time. Please can any one help me to configure "max.poll.records"

```
 public List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs(int maxTasks) {
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> configs = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxTasks; i++) {
      Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
      config.put(ConfigurationConstants.CLUSTER_NAME, clusterName);
      config.put(ConfigurationConstants.HOSTS, hosts);
      config.put(ConfigurationConstants.BULK_SIZE, bulkSize);
      config.put(ConfigurationConstants.IDS, elasticSearchIds);
      config.put(ConfigurationConstants.TOPICS_SATELLITE_DATA, topics);
      config.put(ConfigurationConstants.PUBLISH_TOPIC, topicTopublish);
      config.put(ConfigurationConstants.TYPES, elasticSearchTypes);
      config.put("max.poll.records", "100");

      configs.add(config);
    }
    return configs;
  }
```

Comment: BTW, Confluent 3.1 (released today) includes an Elasticsearch sink connector, in case that would meet your needs. http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.0/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/index.html

Answer (score 9):

You can't override most Kafka consumer configs like `max.poll.records` in the connector configuration. You can do so in the Connect worker configuration though, with a `consumer.` prefix.

Comment: I create a worker.properties and provided the above property in the property file and ran below command.                                                                     sh ./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/worker.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/connector.properties > connectorlogs.log
But getting exception.  org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "connector.class" which has no default value.

Comment: my worker.properties contains                                                                                                                                         "group.id"=operative1.
"operative1.max.poll.records"=1000 and my connector.properties contains proper  "connector.class" but still getting this error.

Comment: you need `consumer.max.poll.records=1000` in the worker config

Comment: Also, it seems you may be adding quotes around the property names, which shouldn't be there. That may be causing the missing `connector.class` error.

Comment: I am not adding quotes in the property file. I just wrote in the comment for readability. The problem I am facing is that Kafka connect is expecting my connector.properties as first parameter instead of worker.properties and that is why its searching for connector.class in worker.properties.

Answer (score 2):

It was solved. I added below configuration in connect-avro-standalone.properties

```
 group.id=mygroup
 consumer.max.poll.records=1000
```

and ran below command for running my connector.

```
sh ./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/connect-elasticsearch-sink.properties
```